# Brownian motion of a particle varying with time

Tags: kinetic-theory, brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

I was thinking about a Brownian particle executing random motion in a liquid. Is there any time dependence if the particle travel some distance say $r$? well, obviously it is time dependence. i think so. but How this distance vary with time? Any concept behind the variation of time with distance?

Comment: It really depends on how you formulate the problem, but using the fact that for Brownian motion $\langle \Delta r^2 \rangle = 6Dt$ where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient, you get that to travel a distance $\Delta r$ the particles will take on average $t=\Delta r^2 / 6 D$, so that $t\propto \Delta r ^2$ i.e. time scales with the distance squared,  it takes 4 times the time to travel 2 times the distance. Different but related questions are when does the particle first arrive at a distance $\Delta r$, after how much time the probability of being in $\Delta r$ is above a given threshold, etc.